# List of ASP.NET Versions?

Tags: asp.net

Thanks to a Q&A on stackoverflow. I just found out how to determine the installed version on my hosting provider's server. Now I need to know what that number means.

Using `<%=Environment.Version%>` on my local machine returns 2.0.50727.3053.

Can someone give me a list of the version 1, 1.1, 2, etc. to the actual `Environment.Version` codes or break down what that code means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[List of .NET Framework versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history).

Comment: The link is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx

This link may also be helpful.

ASP.NET version known as CLR version and .NET Framework version are different.

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to a given .NET framework then all below can have different version at a given point of time:

- .NET Framework
- Common Language Run-time(CLR): Virtual Execution Environment of a process running a .NET EXE
- C#: The programming language you're using to write code
- ASP.NET (Part of .NET Framework library used for web development)

The code `<%=Environment.Version%>` referred in your post gives the version of CLR (2nd bullet point above) while you seem to be interested in version of ASP.NET library.

Each release of .NET Framework has ASP.NET library pre-built in it. All its versions can be found in below link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET