# is asp.net and .net framework version are same? or asp.net or clr version are same?

Tags: .net, asp.net, clr, version, .net-framework-version

***this was my previous question*** 
hi i am new to net framework.
can u tell me is .net framework version and asp.net version are different.
is clr version and asp.net version has some relation.
How can i get asp.net version from the registry.
Can any one give me the version list.
but i am confused with this link on SO- [see the Varun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501/list-of-asp-net-versions)

he said that asp.net version and clr version is same and the .net framework version is different. i also tried to see the installed version of asp in my machine using aspnet_regiis.exe it gives the same version number as of clr (2.0 and 4.0). i also saw the aspnet_isapi.dll only in version 2.0 and 4.0 folder. does that means clr and asp.net version number are same. there is no asp.net version 3.0 and 3.5??? i was quite relaxed with guffa answer, but after seeing this i am confused can anyone help me in knowing is asp.net version and .netframework version are same? or asp.net version and clr version are same? answer with official link will be quite helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, and no.

Most versions of ASP.NET and the CLR correspond, but there are some versions of ASP.NET that comes without a new version of the CLR:

```
 ASP.NET     CLR
-----------------
  1.0        1.0
  1.1        1.1
  2.0        2.0
  3.0        2.0
  3.5        2.0
  4.0        4.0
```

#### Edit:

ASP.NET versions and .NET framework versions are the same. The usage of the ASP.NET versions does however differ a bit depending on what you do.

When you create a web application in Visual Studio, you can specify the target framework. This determines what libraries you can use, so ASP.NET 2.0 and ASP.NET 3.5 have different capabilities. In that sense all the above versions exist.

When you install the application on a web server, all applications in the same application pool have to run the same version of the framework, but it's actually the version of the CLR that is relevant. An ASP.NET 2.0 application can run in the same application pool as an ASP.NET 3.5 application. When you select ASP.NET/framework version in IIS it's actually only the CLR versions that you choose from, so in that sense the ASP.NET version 3.0 and 3.5 does not exist.

Comment: so can i conclude that asp.net version and clr version has the same value. can u give me any link where its officially available. U also said that some asp.net version are different can u give me some name.

Comment: @amod0017: Look at the table above, where for example ASP.NET 3.5 uses CLR 2.0. You can find that information for example on this Microsoft page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99txfy5.aspx

Comment: thnx for the help. this is quite near to what i wanted.

Comment: i have some confusion thats y edited the question can u help me out regarding it.

Comment: @amod0017: I added a clarification above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ASP.NET solutions, Console applications, Windows Forms and WPF applications and such-and-so, all use the same CLR (according to their version.)

Comment: [.NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) != [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) - See Guffa's list.

Comment: so can i conclude that asp.net version and clr version has the same value. can u give me any link where its officially available.

Comment: @ Lucero yaa i know that clr version and .net framework version are not same. but is asp.net version and .net version are same???

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET is part of the .NET Framework, so their version is always in sync. Bot not each version of the .NET Framework has its own CLR, specifically the framework versions from V2.0 up to and including V3.5 do all use the same CLR (V2.0).

Comment: @Lecero: I didn't say they were equal. But that each .NET version is run by a corresponding runtime.