# .net FW version and asp.net version?

Tags: asp.net, .net, frameworks

Regarding a typical error like :

[image]

It says :

Version Information: `Microsoft .NET Framework Version`:4.0.30319; `ASP.NET Version`:4.0.30319.1008

So  - the FW version is `4.0.30319` , and the asp.net major version is also 4.

But what does the `1008` part in `4.0.30319.1008`  mean ?  does it mean that there were 1008 builds under the fw4 just for asp.net usage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling '4.0.30319.1008' suggests that this is the runtime version; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6409357/1854461) for a brief explanation of how the ASP.NET versions relate to those of the CLR.

[This list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions) also suggests that the build numbers persist in the framework as a whole; see for example the bottom of the list where major versions correspond to incremental build numbers of 4.0.30319 (e.g. 4.5.50709 and 4.0.30319.17929).

Comment: I dont understand how it answers my question. Ive searched in both link the `1008` and couldn't find any.

Comment: Well `1008` is not explicitly mentioned but they give an understanding of the versioning. Google `4.0.30319.1008`, it's the runtime version so the ASP.NET version is referring to that.