# Why is Mono for mac showing a lower version than my project targets?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mono

I'm new to Mono.
I developed a .NET MVC project on Windows and have switched to a Mac.
I got my project running but with some errors.

When a 500 error occurs, the Mono web server displays an error page and on the bottom of that page, I see ASP.Net 4.0.30319.42000.

But my project targets .Net 4.8.

My understanding is that the ASP.Net version will be the same as the .Net version as per
[is asp.net and .net framework version are same? or asp.net or clr version are same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409259/)

This would explain my errors since I need features from Net45 and up.

I cannot find anywhere in visual studio to control this. My project settings show .NET 4.8 as does my web.config.

As a test I commented out all assembly references in the  section as well as the httpRuntime declaration in my web.config to make sure I was not overwriting something. This had no effect.

Mono version 6.12.0
Visual Studio 2022 Mac

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: If you are not new to .NET, you should know that 4.0.30319 is the CLR version number, while 4.8 is the Framework version. Well, don't waste any time on Mono, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/

Comment: Thank you! Alas, I have given up on this. Had to move on with a different approach.